# gentoo at vmware, DnD and resizing aren't working

Tags: drag-and-drop, resize, vmware, gentoo

Drag and Drop isnt work, resizing too. Only copy-paste is work sometimes.
I thought that it is becouse vmblock errors, but after "emerge vmware-modules" vmblock errors gone and problem still exists.
Host OS - Windows.

```
al .cache # equery list -i xorg-server
 * Searching for xorg-server ...
[IP-] [  ] x11-base/xorg-server-1.16.4:0/1.16.1

al log # lsmod | grep vm
vmblock                 9176  0
vmci                   57829  0

al log # eselect kernel list;
Available kernel symlink targets:
  [1]   linux-4.1.12-gentoo *

al log # ls /usr/src;
linux  linux-4.1.12-gentoo

al vmblock # ls /proc/fs/vmblock
dev  mountPoint
```

http://pastebin.com/jKSFqzrU
http://prntscr.com/9f6qzx
http://prntscr.com/9f6r4k
http://pastebin.com/ZcAa5CWG
http://pastebin.com/4AZRZPL8
http://pastebin.com/gDdn3FG5